# Groovy wslite library support for http connection pooling

Tags: soap, groovy, groovyws

I am using groovy wslite library(https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) for consuming SOAP service, it is so simple and very effective but i didn't see any connection pooling while creating http conections under the hood.
Isn't creating a new connection everytime is expensive? trying understand whether it is good practice or not?